# Question from the 2011 IMC (International Mathematics Competition) Key Stage III paper, about the evaluation of a quadratic equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, quadratics, problem-solving, telescopic-series

> When $a=1, 2, 3, ..., 2010, 2011$, the roots of the equation $x^2-2x-a^2-a=0$ are $(a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2), (a_3, b_3),\cdots, (a_{2010}, b_{2010}), (a_{2011}, b_{2011})$ respectively. Evaluate:
>
> $$
> \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{b_1} + \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{b_2} + \frac{1}{a_3} + \frac{1}{b_3} +\cdots + \frac{1}{a_{2010}} + \frac{1}{b_{2010}} + \frac{1}{a_{2011}} + \frac{1}{b_{2011}}
> $$

I tried solving this question, with the use of the quadratic equation.

Using the quadratic equation, I concluded that $a_1=\frac{2+\sqrt{12}}{2}=1+\sqrt{3}$ and that $b_1=\frac{2-\sqrt{12}}{2}=1-\sqrt{3}$. The reason that I concluded to this is because the quadratic equation states:

$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

So I substituted $a$ with $1$ ($1$ is multiplying $x^2$, in the original equation), $b$ with $-2$ ($x$ is getting multiplied by $-2$ in the original equation) and $c$ with $(-a^2-a)$, as they are the only ones which are not getting directly multiplied by $x$ in the original equation.

Hence, I subsequently worked out that $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{b_1} = \frac{2}{-2}=-1$

Continuing to do the same thing I worked out $\frac{1}{a_2} + \frac{1}{b_2}= \frac{2}{-6} = -\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{a3} + \frac{1}{b_3}= \frac{2}{-12}=-\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{a_4} + \frac{1}{b_4} = \frac{2}{-20}=-\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{1}{a_5} + \frac{1}{b5} = \frac{2}{-30} =-\frac{1}{15}$.

I subsequently realised that a pattern was emerging, the denominator, each time is getting increased by the degree of $n$ at which $a$ and $b$ are (for instance $\frac{1}{a_4} + \frac{1}{b_4}= -\frac{1}{6+4}$)

Had I not been dealing with fractions, I would have solved it using arithmetic progressions, but unfortunately that is not possible.

I can think of no other way of finishing off my thoughts, nor any other way to solve this problem. Can you please help me? Can you please tell me if there is any method of finishing off my thoughts and if there isn't, can you please suggest a method of solving the problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I've already tried using series, but i have not been able to solve it

Comment: Any other suggestions, are welcome

Comment: My first thought is to "complete the square".  The given equation, $x^2- 2x- a^2- a$ is the same as $x^2- 2x= a^2+ a$.  We can "complete the square" on the left by adding 1 to both sides: $x^2- 2x+ 1= (x- 1)^2= a^2+ a+ 1$.  So $x- 1= \pm\sqrt{a^2+ a}$ and $x= 1\pm\sqrt{a^2+ a}$.  For so  So when a=1, the roots are $a_1= 1+ \sqrt{2}$ and $b_1= 1- \sqrt{2}$.  $\frac{1}{a_1}+ \r

Comment: You found a pattern in the expressions $1/a_i + 1/b_i$. Can you also find a pattern in the partial sums you get by adding them together one by one?

Comment: I've already looked for one, but nothing's coming to me

Comment: My first thought is to "complete the square".  The given equation, $x^2- 2x- a^2- a$ is the same as $x^2- 2x= a^2+ a$.  We can "complete the square" on the left by adding 1 to both sides: $x^2- 2x+ 1= (x- 1)^2= a^2+ a+ 1$.  So $x- 1= \pm\sqrt{a^2+ a}$ and $x= 1\pm\sqrt{a^2+ a}$.  Now pair the reciprocals: $\frac{1}{a_i}+ \frac{1}{b_i}= \frac{1}{1+ \sqrt{a^2+ a}}+ \frac{1- \sqrt{a^2+ a}}= \frac{1- \sqrt{a^2+ a}}{1- a^2- a}+ $$ \frac{1+ \sqrt{a^2+ a}}{1- a^2- a}= \frac{2}{1- a^2- a}$.  The sum of reciprocals reduces to $-2- \frac{2}{5}- \frac{2}{11}- \frac{2}{19}- ...$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having difficulties, seeing how, through completing the square, the problem can be solved, can you please show us, how the answer could be found, using you're method?

Comment: What can you say about the denominators, 1, 5, 11, 19, …?  Do you see, from the pattern, that the next denominator after "19" must be 29?  That the difference from one denominator to the next is increasing by 2 each time? That is enough to tell us the formula for the denominators is quadratic.  It should not be two difficult, then, to see that the denominators are given by $n^2+ n- 1$.

Comment: It would help if you identified the denominators as triangular numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2011}\left(\frac{1}{a_k}+\frac{1}{b_k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{2011}\frac{a_k+b_k}{a_kb_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2011}\frac{2}{-k(k+1)}=$$
$$=-2\sum_{k=1}^{2011}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=-2\left(1-\frac{1}{2012}\right)=-\frac{2011}{1006}.$$

Comment: You're a genius

Comment: Thank you very much and I wish I had you as a maths teacher

Comment: @kenith You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: can I get in touch with you again if I have further problems?

Comment: Just post it in another topic.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to "complete the square".  The given equation, $x^2- 2x- a^2- a$ is the same as $x^2- 2x= a^2+ a$.  We can "complete the square" on the left by adding 1 to both sides: $x^2- 2x+ 1= (x- 1)^2= a^2+ a+ 1$.  So $x- 1= \pm\sqrt{a^2+ a}$ and $x= 1\pm\sqrt{a^2+ a}$.  Now pair the reciprocals: $\frac{1}{a_i}+ \frac{1}{b_i}= \frac{1}{1+ \sqrt{a^2+ a}}+ \frac{1- \sqrt{a^2+ a}}= \frac{1- \sqrt{a^2+ a}}{1- a^2- a}+ $$ \frac{1+ \sqrt{a^2+ a}}{1- a^2- a}= \frac{2}{1- a^2- a}$.  The sum of reciprocals reduces to $-2- \frac{2}{5}- \frac{2}{11}- \frac{2}{19}- ...$.

Comment: Completing the square is fine, but it should be $x-1=\pm \sqrt{a^2+a+1}$. And then: $\frac1{a_i}+\frac1{b_i}=-\frac2{a^2+a}$, so it is a round way. Easier to use Vieta's: $\frac1{a_i}+\frac1{b_i}=\frac{a_i+b_i}{a_ib_i}$. Luck.